# How to create table with its columns based from the parameter passed from function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I want to create a function or stored procedure that will create the table in PostgreSQL with its columns based from the parameter passed through the function.

The example of the parameter will be in `jsonb` type, like this:

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isRequired": true
        },
        {
            "name": "type",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isRequired": false
        },
        {
            "name": "id",
            "dataType": "Text",
            "isRequired": true
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to achieve is create the column based on the `name` field along with their  `dataType` and `isRequired` will represents the `NULL` or `NOT NULL`.

Currently I have my function look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table(tableName text, metadata json) RETURNS VOID AS
    $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE (SELECT format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s);', $1, y.cols)
                 FROM (SELECT string_agg((s.details ->> 'name')::text || ' ' || (s.details->>'dataType')::text || ' ' || CASE WHEN (s.details->>'isRequired') = 'true'
                                  THEN 'NOT NULL'
                                  ELSE 'NULL'
                                  END, '', '') AS cols
                       FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(metadata) as details) s ) y);
    END
    $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

But this gave me error:
`function string_agg(text, unknown, unknown) does not exist`.

Ultimately I wanted a query look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE type_1 (
  name TEXT  NOT NULL,
  type TEXT  NULL,
  id   TEXT  NOT NULL
);
```

If anyone knows how to do this I deeply appreciated it, thank you!

Comment: You don't need to pass 3rd parameter in string_agg() and also try casting string_agg(expression, ' '::text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with a few tweaks:

- removed undue third argument in string_agg, as remarked by @maddy23285
- replaced positional argument reference (`$1`, `$2`), out of personal preference
- Text => `text`, in the jsonb definition
- assigning the constructed statement to a variable makes debugging easier ; I made the function return the statement as `text` for the purpose of the demo, revert to void if desired

Feel free to reformat to fix mixed case

```sql
/*
 * Create a table named tableName, from column definitions as jsonb.
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73369116/how-to-create-table-with-its-columns-based-from-the-parameter-passed-from-functi#73369116
 */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table(tableName text, metadata jsonb) RETURNS text AS
$def$
    
declare
    statement text;
    
BEGIN

    select format($$
        create table %s (
          %s
        );
        $$,
        quote_ident(tableName), -- caveat, some engines might require group by tableName
        string_agg(format('%s %s %s',
            quote_ident(col->>'name'),
            quote_ident(col->>'dataType'),
            case col->>'isRequired' when 'true' then 'not null' else 'null' end
        ), ', ')
    ) as statement
    from jsonb_array_elements(metadata -> 'columns') col
    into statement;

    -- use this to debug the statement, `listen debug;` in psql or other client
    -- perform pg_notify('debug', statement);

    execute statement;
    
    return statement;

END;
$def$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bbfdad74928d341e5a6eb130a082ac63)

Comment: Thank you so much this works! Just out of curious, if one of the field is `int` instead of `text`,  which part shall I change? I see no fix for data type in here but `int` will not work.
By the way `bool` works.

Comment: @Corene my bad, `quote_ident` adds double-quotes that the engine fails to interpret. Remove `quote_ident` around `col->>'dataType'` (but mind your input - dynamic create table sounds like a quick way to trouble ;)